# How to get tarantool version from command line interface?

Tags: tarantool

I can get tarantool client version using this command:

```
$ tarantool --version
Tarantool 2.5.2-50-g0cb9a4bba
```

but how can I get the tarantool server version inside the terminal?

```
tarantoolctl connect 3301                                          
connected to localhost:3301
localhost:3301>
---
- error: '[string "return version()"]:1: attempt to call global ''version'' (a nil
    value)'
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to obtain the version:

```
tarantool> _TARANTOOL
---
- 2.7.0-74-g71377c28e
...
tarantool> require('tarantool').version
---
- 2.7.0-74-g71377c28e
...
tarantool> box.info.version -- only after box.cfg{<...>}
---
- 2.7.0-74-g71377c28e
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, found it

```
box.info.version
---
- 2.6.0-0-g47aa4e01e
```